# Python numpy nditer skipping alternate elements

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, iterator

I am trying to iterate over two 2D arrays. But, somehow iterator skips every alternate element in row. 'bimg' and 'dist'size is 20x12. But, for every row, it iterates over 0, 2, 4 ... columns instead of 0,1,2,3,4, ...

**Code snippet:**

```
it = np.nditer([bimg, dist], 
               op_flags=[['readonly'],['readonly']], 
               flags = ['multi_index', 'multi_index'])
rows, cols = bimg.shape
print "bimg dimensions: ", bimg.shape
print "dist dimensions: ", dist.shape
for cur_b, cur_d in it:
    print "MULTI_IDX = ", it.multi_index
```

**Output:**

```
bimg dimensions:  (20L, 12L)
dist dimensions:  (20L, 12L)
MULTI_IDX =  (0, 0)
MULTI_IDX =  (0, 2)
MULTI_IDX =  (0, 4)
MULTI_IDX =  (0, 6)
MULTI_IDX =  (0, 8)
MULTI_IDX =  (0, 10)
MULTI_IDX =  (1, 0)
MULTI_IDX =  (1, 2)
```

To understand this issue, if I create array on python prompt and try to iterate over it works correctly:

**Correctly working code:**

```
x = np.array(np.arange(240))
x = x.reshape(20,12)
y = np.array(np.arange(240))
y = y + 100
y = y.reshape(20,12)
it = np.nditer([x,y], 
               op_flags = [['readonly'],['readonly']], 
               flags= ['multi_index', 'multi_index'])
for a, b in it:
    print it.multi_index
```

**Output:**

```
MULTI_INDEX =  (0, 0)
MULTI_INDEX =  (0, 1)
MULTI_INDEX =  (0, 2)
MULTI_INDEX =  (0, 3)
MULTI_INDEX =  (0, 4)
MULTI_INDEX =  (0, 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the difference.  When I define:

```
bimg = x
dist = y
```

I get the same iteration with both clips.

`flags` only needs 'multi_index' once.  It applies to the whole iteration, `op_flags` to each array:

```
flags= ['multi_index']
```

While the documentation describes `nditer` as `efficient multi-dimensional iterator object`, it doesn't seem to help much with speed in Python code.  In C or Cython is streamlines the whole process of iterating over multiple array.

Here's another way of generating the `multi_index`.  Actually it's not so different.  Internally `ndindex` constructs a dummy array of the desired shape, and returns an iterable.  Look at its code.

```
for i, j in np.ndindex(bimg.shape):
     print i,j
```

According the tutorial `Iterating over Array` page, the correct way to use `multi_index` is with the `c` style iterator:

```
while not it.finished:
    print it.multi_index
    it.iternext()
```

I'm not sure why. What are the `dtypes` of `bimg` and `dist`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out 'while not it.finished'. In fact, I was using it earlier, but then changed it to 'for', but forgot to remove it.iternext(). So, that was causing jump in iteration.